# Unstable behavior of a library (UnsatisfiedLinkError) in Eclipse/Gradle multi-projects

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, gradle, java-native-interface

Initially there were 2 Gradle sub-projects. The main "app" and the "lib" services.
In "app" there was a resources directory which hosted a custom library (library built directly in this directory so that it is immediately integrated into the project). But at one point, an extension to the library caused a signature error and while looking for a solution I tried a proposal (found on the net) which consisted of invoking the "Clean Build Folder" feature of Xcode. The signature issue has not been resolved but all sources of "app" have been erased.

Following this adventure, I made the decision to create a third Gradle sub-project ("oslib") which would only contain the library and the Java code that carries the JNI. At least if the source removal were to happen again, the restoration would be much less expensive than in the main project.

Once the signature problem was resolved, the library was able to continue to evolve and the tests were carried out normally until a system error (crash) occurred. Nothing abnormal, a library bug that manifests itself in its own way.

Except that from this moment (without changing anything in the Java environment), any attempt to access the library resulted in an UnsatisfiedLinkError on the native Java method invoked.
The library loaded without error but the behavior was identical to that of an absent library.
I don't understand why there is now this change in behavior. To see what happens I reproduced the problem with the simplest possible code and what emerges adds even more to my confusion:

The file «AppLib.h»

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <simd/simd.h>
#import <jni.h>

#ifndef _Included_AppLib
#define _Included_AppLib
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_test_TestJni_testNative (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj);   

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

The file «AppLib.m»

```
#import <simd/simd.h>
#import <AppKit/NSApplication.h>
#import <AppKit/NSWindow.h>

#import "AppLib.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_test_TestJni_testNative (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    NSLog(@"CALL Java_test_TestJni_testNative");
}
```

And here the code of the access classes via the JNI of the "oslib" sub-project which contains the library in its resources directory:

```
package test;

public class MainClassProj3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestJni.test();
    }

}
```

Here, in the "loadLibrary ()" method, the library is copied into a temporary directory (so that it works from a jar file later) then loaded from this directory. In comment there will be the possibility to load the library directly (it is important for the continuation).

```
package test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class LibraryLoader {

    public static void loadLibrary(final String libPath, final String libName) {
        try {
            final String srcPath = (((libPath == null) || libPath.isEmpty()) ? "" : ("/" + libPath)) + "/" + libName;
            final String outPath = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + libName;
            final InputStream in = LibraryLoader.class.getResourceAsStream(srcPath);
            final OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(outPath));
            
            in.transferTo(out);
            in.close();
            out.close();
            
            System.out.println(outPath);
            System.load(outPath);
            
//          System.load("/var/folders/4t/wfx1sb3d2b7d82x56zmr3l1h0000gn/T/libAppLib.dylib");
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Here, the class that makes the link with the library.

```
package test;

public class TestJni {

    static {
        LibraryLoader.loadLibrary("", "libAppLib.dylib");
    }

    public native static void testNative();
    
    public static void test() {
        testNative();
    }
}
```

Here is the code of the main class of the “app” sub-project which accesses the services of the “oslib” sub-project (the call to the native method).

```
package test;

public class MainClassProj1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestJni.test();
    }

}
```

If I invoke the call to the library from the main class of the first project (“app” sub-project) I get an error.
The library seems to load correctly (no exception) but access to the native method behaves as if the library was not loaded :

```
/var/folders/4t/wfx1sb3d2b7d82x56zmr3l1h0000gn/T/libAppLib.dylib
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'void test.TestJni.testNative()'
    at test.TestJni.testNative(Native Method)
    at test.TestJni.test(TestJni.java:12)
    at test.MainClassProj1.main(MainClassProj1.java:6)
```

If I invoke the call to the library from the main of the third project (“oslib” sub-project) the operation is correct :

```
/var/folders/4t/wfx1sb3d2b7d82x56zmr3l1h0000gn/T/libAppLib.dylib
2021-07-19 19:39:38.788 java[14357:530171] CALL Java_test_TestJni_testNative
```

If I try again with the first project the error remains the same.

```
/var/folders/4t/wfx1sb3d2b7d82x56zmr3l1h0000gn/T/libAppLib.dylib
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'void test.TestJni.testNative()'
    at test.TestJni.testNative(Native Method)
    at test.TestJni.test(TestJni.java:12)
    at test.MainClassProj1.main(MainClassProj1.java:6)
```

The library is copied into the temporary directory each time LibraryLoader.loadLibrary (String, String) is called and is never deleted. So since the first test it is present in "/var/folders/4t/wfx1sb3d2b7d82x56zmr3l1h0000gn/T".
So by replacing the content of the LibraryLoader.loadLibrary (String, String) method:

```
public class LibraryLoader {

    public static void loadLibrary(final String libPath, final String libName) {
        try {
//          final String srcPath = (((libPath == null) || libPath.isEmpty()) ? "" : ("/" + libPath)) + "/" + libName;
//          final String outPath = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + libName;
//          final InputStream in = LibraryLoader.class.getResourceAsStream(srcPath);
//          final OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(outPath));
//          
//          in.transferTo(out);
//          in.close();
//          out.close();
//          
//          System.out.println(outPath);
//          System.load(outPath);
            
            System.load("/var/folders/4t/wfx1sb3d2b7d82x56zmr3l1h0000gn/T/libAppLib.dylib");
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

If I run the first project again, the error persists.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'void test.TestJni.testNative()'
    at test.TestJni.testNative(Native Method)
    at test.TestJni.test(TestJni.java:12)
    at test.MainClassProj1.main(MainClassProj1.java:6)
```

If I run right after the third project the error occurs (new behavior).

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'void test.TestJni.testNative()'
    at test.TestJni.testNative(Native Method)
    at test.TestJni.test(TestJni.java:12)
    at test.MainClassProj3.main(MainClassProj3.java:6)
```

Now I change again the contents of LibraryLoader.loadLibrary (String, String) to return to its initial version (the library is copied into the temporary directory before being loaded) then I just run the third project. Everything is fine :

```
/var/folders/4t/wfx1sb3d2b7d82x56zmr3l1h0000gn/T/libAppLib.dylib
2021-07-19 20:03:30.308 java[19075:553720] CALL Java_test_TestJni_testNative
```

I change again the contents of LibraryLoader.loadLibrary (String, String) to return to its version without a library copy then I just run the third project.
This time there is no error:

```
2021-07-19 20:06:55.747 java[19711:557089] CALL Java_test_TestJni_testNative
```

And now I run the first project again and this time no error either.

```
2021-07-19 20:10:05.934 java[20337:560000] CALL Java_test_TestJni_testNative
```

If I repeat what I have just described in order, I get exactly the same result.
Note that running this code from a jar file works perfectly.

Does anyone have an explanation for such behavior?

How can a sequence of independent executions which access a read-only file (the library which in the resources directory of the "oslib" sub-project is not modified at any time) can cause or resolve an instability?

Mac OS version is 10.15.2
Java version is OpenJDK 15.0.3
XCode version is 11.7
Eclipse version is 2021-06 (4.20.0)

Answer (score 1):

I have a workaround which I don't like very much but which unblocks me and which consists in identifying my development environment and going to look for the library directly in its resources directory. Hoping it stays stable.

In the "LibraryLoader.loadLibrary()" method :

```
public class LibraryLoader {
    
    public static void loadLibrary(final String libPath, final String libName) {
        try {
            final String appPath = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")).toString();
            final String srcPath = (((libPath == null) || libPath.isEmpty()) ? "" : ("/" + libPath)) + "/" + libName;
            final String outPath = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + libName;
            final InputStream in = LibraryLoader.class.getResourceAsStream(srcPath);
            final OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(outPath));
            final String devPath;
            
            if (appPath.startsWith("/Users/ ... absolute path of the main project ... /app")) {
                devPath = appPath.replaceAll("app", "oslib/src/main/ ... path where the library is located ... /" + srcPath);
                System.load(devPath);
            }
            else {
                
                in.transferTo(out);
                in.close();
                out.close();
                
                System.out.println(outPath);
                System.load(outPath);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ...
        }
    }

}
```